# The IDE says my (brand new) Arduino UNO is on COM 1

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I recently bought an Arduino Uno and installed everything necessary. I tried it on both USB ports on my computer. However, the Ports menu only shows COM1. There is a line on the bottom of the IDE which says Arduino Uno on COM1.

Any program I try fails to upload to the board. When I tried the Blink example, the following error message appeared:

```
Arduino: 1.6.3 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Sketch uses 1,030 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.

Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for
local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x43

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x43
```

and so on. Until,

```
This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation" enabled in File > Preferences.
```

I have a Windows 7 64 bit desktop.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try pressing the reset (hardware on arduino) button directly after pressing the upload button (software in IDE)? - I had this problem on a cheap Nano clone, using the wrong programmer type

Comment: It does not seem to be making any difference. Is there something else you think I ought to do?

Comment: I read in many places that the Arduino UNO is supposed to be on COM 3 or higher. How do I do that? It always says I'm on COM1. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you find the arduino in `Windows - Device Manager`?

Comment: @FuaZe -  No, I cannot.

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of your device manager? There might be an issue with the drivers, might also check the error in google, that's how I fixed mine

Comment: its possible that your COM1 device has nothing to do with the arduino and is some other device on your computer, and that your arduino is not being recognized at all. The "Arduino uno on COM*" line reflects your settings, not anything the IDE has detected about the available ports.

Comment: @SR1 - which port the Arduino will be on depends *entirely* on the details of your system.  There is no rule.  On a system with no other serial devices, COM1 is a legitimate possibility.

Comment: @SR1 could you indicate what solved your problem, maybe add it yourself as an answer to your question

Comment: @Joram - Turns out my USB cable was faulty. While the green light still turned on, the computer did not recognize the Arduino Uno R3. I installed some of the FTDI USB drivers and used a different cable, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few troubleshooting tips:

1. First check if the board is listed as Arduino Uno in the IDE by going to Tools --> Board
2. Check this [site](http://redhotengineer.blogspot.com/2014/11/my-fight-with-avrdude-stk500getsync-not.html).
3. Also, try reinstalling the driver.
4. Check your cable.
5. As a last resort you can try re uploading the bootloader.